# Bloqueo de outlook para automatizar emails con python

Tags: python, azure, smtp, outlook

he hecho un script de python que accede automaticamente a un email de outlook, descarga los emails y envía una respuesta. Actualmente microsoft ha eliminado, por lo que entiendo, poder acceder con imaplib o smtplib. Por lo que he leído ahora es necesario desplegar la aplicación en el Active Directory de Azure. Mi pregunta es si hay algún otro método que me permita hacer esto sin utilizar Azure.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final Microsoft no bloqueó del todo la autenticación simple,

> no hay planes para deshabilitar la autenticación básica para los clientes SMTP AUTH en este momento.

De igual forma puede revisar la documentación oficial aquí **[Cómo configurar una aplicación o dispositivo multifunción para enviar correos electrónicos mediante Office 365 o Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365?source=recommendations)**

¡Espero que esto te ayude!

NOTA: Editada la respuesta en función a la recomendación de [padaleiana](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/156327/padaleiana)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que los enlaces podrían romperse, volviendo inválida la respuesta más adelante. Pon el contenido esencial del enlace en tu respuesta. Recuerda que la información debe ser útil no solo para el autor de la pregunta, sino también para los demás usuarios que lleguen a tener un problema similar posteriormente.